# Matching Word, then between delimiters in PHP With Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Having a bit of a difficult time working out a regular expression that will do what I need. Basically, I am parsing through a file with several thousand lines of text, and looking for anything with the line:

EXAM:

Matched text will always be in the format:

EXAM: (teststring) extra text

So what I am trying to do is match on EXAM: , then pull in everything within the parenthesis.

My current expression:

```
/^.+?\EXAM:(.+)$/is
```

pulls in everything after EXAM: , which won't work for this application.

Comment: are you processing one line at a time? please show your code

Comment: Ibu, one line at a time. 

if(preg_match("/^.+?\EXAM:(.+)$/is", $thisline, $matches))
    {
     $exam_type = trim($matches[1]);
    }

Comment: Can there be parenthesis symbols inside `teststring` or `extra test`?

Comment: Robin, no, never...it will always be:
EXAM: (text1) text2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(?<=EXAM: \()([^)]+)
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/nD3sQ2

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/EXAM:\s*\(([^)]+)\)/i`:

```
if(preg_match("/EXAM:\s*\(([^)]+)\)/i", $thisline, $matches)) {
    $exam_type = trim($matches[1]);
}
```

`[^)]` will match anything except a closing parenthesis, and it will stop at the first `)` encountered. You need to escape parenthesis as they are special regex characters (they are used to capture variables). Here for example you use the unescaped ones to store what you want.
`\s` is a shortcut for any type of whitespace (space, tab...).
You probably don't need the `s` at the end since you are parsing the doc line by line: the `s` flag only makes the `.` match newline on top of everything else.